# How to check user input?

Tags: c++

SO I want to be able to invalidate all user input except a certain word, like `'K'` or `'C'`. I'm not sure at all how to do this. So if they mispell it to "celcius" or "husdhfjae", my program would say `"Input invalid, please enter K or C."`

Please nothing too complicated, because I just started. Thank you :)

```
//  CS 575,HW #1B, Ravela Smyth

//  This program converts from Fahrenheit to Celsius or Kelvin

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    double Fahrenheit, celsius, kelvin;
    cout << "Hi! What is the weather today in Fahrenheit?? " << endl;
    cin >> Fahrenheit;
    cout << "Would you like to convert this temperature to Celsius or Kelvin? (C/K)" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "C")
    {
          celsius = (5 * (Fahrenheit - 32)) / 9;
          cout << "Today's weather in Celsius is " << celsius << " degrees! " << endl;
    }
    else if (input == "c")
    {
          celsius = (5 * (Fahrenheit - 32)) / 9;
          cout << "Today's weather in Celsius is " << celsius << " degrees! " << endl;
    }
    else if (input == "K")
    {
          kelvin = (5 * (Fahrenheit + 459.67)) / 9;
          cout << "Today's weather in Kelvin is " << kelvin << " degrees!" << endl;
    }
    else if (input == "k")
    {
          kelvin = (5 * (Fahrenheit + 459.67)) / 9;
          cout << "Today's weather in Kelvin is " << kelvin << " degrees!" << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually user inputs are checked using `while` or `do...while` loops.
The idea is simple, you always get back to the same error message and read again the input until it is correct.

The advantage of placing the valid options in the single `string` is to allow easy addition or removal of the options without dealing with long `if` conditions.

I believe something simple like this will do the job:

```
std::string valid_options("kKcC");
std::string input;
bool illegal_input;

std::cout << "Would you like to convert this temperature to Celsius or Kelvin? (C/K)" << std::endl;
std::cin >> input;
// check that only one letter was provided and it belongs to the valid options
while (input.size() != 1 || valid_options.find(input) == std::string::npos)
{
    std::cout << "Input invalid, please enter K or C.\n";
    std::cin >> input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can do something like if(input == "C" || input == "c")
Or you can convert the input to lower/upper case

Second, you can add an else statement that says something like "please enter a valid command". Play around with it, you can even use loops to wait for correct input!

Comment: I'm confused on how to write "all else" in my code. Can you give an example?

Comment: If (input == "c" || input == "C"){ //do something} else { //all else } check it out here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_if_else_statement.htm

Comment: @RavelaSmyth the else statement covers all other cases

Comment: the "c" "C" thing is to say only accept those two am I correct?

Comment: @RavelaSmyth yea! The || statement means OR. An OR statement evaluates to true if either of the two arguments are true. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f355wky8.aspx

Comment: Actually, how do I make it loop back to the beginning question if the input is not c

Comment: Also, can I have more than 2 or variable? like K, k, C, c

Comment: @RavelaSmyth try figuring out what a do while loop is! That's definitely in the right direction :)

Comment: @RavelaSmyth you can group the ones that have like processes together. Like the "c"s and the "k"s

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to test the input against a container of all valid inputs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool valid(std::string s,std::vector<std::string> y)
{
    std::sort(y.begin(), y.end());
    return std::binary_search(y.begin(), y.end(), s);
}
int main()
{
    std::string s;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter K or C: ";
        std::cin >> s;
    } while (!valid(s, { "K","C","k","c" }));

    std::cout << "good!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a while loop. This is probably the simplest way to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string word;
    std::cin >> word;
    //Keep asking for a word until this condition is false, i.e.
    //word will be equal to one of these letters
    while(word != "C" && word != "c" && word != "K" && word != "k")
    {
            std::cout << "Invalid temperature type: " << word << " Use 'K' or 'C'" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> word;
    }

    if (word == "C" || word == "c")
    {
        std::cout << "Celsius" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (word == "K" || word == "k")
    {
        std::cout << "Kelvin" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while getting the correct user input for that i wrote a simple solution i hope it will be helpfull for everyone getting started with c++.

```
//get user input
char input;
cin >> input;
//convert the input to lowercase 
char Temp = tolower(input);
//check the input (not valid input will clear the user input)
while(!(cin >> input) || ((Temp != 'c') &&( Temp != 'k')){
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Invalid input. Please, try again: ";
}
//evalute input cases
switch (Temp)
{
case 'c':
    /* celcius */
    break;

case 'k':
    /* Kelvin */
    break;

}
```